# Why onAppear not executed?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a content view in SwiftUI that has a navigation link to go to another view CurrenciesView().

```
type hereimport SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
//    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
//
//    @FetchRequest(
//        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
//        animation: .default)
//    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Text("Check today's USD currency")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,  alignment: .leading)
                NavigationLink {
                    CurrenciesView()
                } label: {
                    Text("Search for currencies")
                }

                Divider()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Rapid Booking")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

The CurrenciesView():

```
import SwiftUI

struct CurrenciesView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var vm = CurrenciesViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            if vm.isLoading{
                ProgressView()
            }
            else{
                List{
                    ForEach((vm.currency?.exchange_rates)!, id: \.currency){ rate in
                        CurrencyItem(rate: rate.exchange_rate_buy ?? "Unknown", currency: rate.currency ?? "Unknown")
                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .navigationTitle("\(vm.currency?.base_currency_date ?? "Unknown")'s USD rate")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: vm.fetchCurrency)
        .alert(isPresented: $vm.hasError, error: vm.error) {
            Button {
                vm.fetchCurrency()
            } label: {
                Text("Cancel")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct CurrenciesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CurrenciesView()
    }
}

struct CurrencyItem: View{
    
    let rate: String
    let currency: String
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("**Currency**: \(currency)")
            Divider()
            Text("**Rate**: \(rate)")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
               alignment: .leading)
        .padding()
        .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
    }
}
```

The Currencies view always force unwrap a nil value in the ForEach since the vm didn't execute the function to parse data from API. I set it up in the onAppear() but it was never triggered.

I set up break points on the onAppear() and run on Simulator but it didn't enter into that break point, shouldn't it go to the break point first?

Comment: I'm assuming `isLoading` only gets set to `true` once `fetchCurrency` is called, so there's a situation where `isLoading` is `false` but `vm.currency` is `nil`, which will cause a crash because you're force-unwrapping. In general you shouldn't force-unwrap optionals at all, and in your specific case I'd use an `enum` to store your View Model's state.

Comment: a simple fix to avoid the forced unwrapping crash, is to use something like: `if let rates = vm.currency?.exchange_rates {
           ForEach(rates, id: \.currency){ .... }`, or before the `List`

Answer (score 0):

Rename `CurrenciesViewModel` to `CurrencyFetcher` and do the initial fetch in the class's `init`. `@StateObject` is init just before body is called. `onAppear` is for external actions when the auto-generated `UIView` object appears, it's not really designed for lazy loading data. SwiftUI's design expects the data prepared in advance, and the `View` struct hierarchy is a function of that state.